# The issue to restore .bak on the older version of MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

A few weeks ago I took Microsoft course "20761C Querying Data with Transact-SQL". 
My instructor pointed to the site https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/companion-moc.aspx where we could download Labfiles and play with it.

I tried but hit the problem: I am running SQL Server 2012 and 2014 but the `.bak` file was created on 2016. Hence I can't restore it.

I am using Windows 7 which does not support SQL Server 2016. Are you aware of any site that has older version of backup or etc?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Ask your instructor?

Comment: You could install a hypervisor (e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) with a newer Windows OS image and install SQL Server 2016 Developer or Express Edition on that for your testing.

Comment: This is a good idea but I don't have Windows image 2016 hence I have to buy it. Well it's not in my plan just for this exercise . But anyway ... thanks for suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

Have your instructor or someone who has the database installed to generate the scripts to the database. You do this by right  clicking on the database. Then go to Task/Generate scripts.

[image]

Comment: Well the class is already over and I don't have access anymore to instructor. 
Someone from another forum suggested to download version 2012 of the Lab files from the same site. I did it. It does not have .bak file but rather a bunch of scripts to create and insert. Well it's not the same as our Lab in class but very similar and I think I'll try to follow this path. Thanks anyway

Comment: - Folks, how to mark this ticket as 'completed' or 'answered'? Thanks